# Any advice using ISP’s Modem/Router Combo with internet switch

Tags: router, switch, isp, modem

I just bought myself a internet switch, because I could not use any ports on my own router (I'm going to add another pc later). Before installing everything I want to ask you if this method I want to use is correct?

```
    *Internet Switch model: TP-LINK TL-SG108PE
    *ASUS Router Model: ASUS RT-AX88U
    *ISP Router is connected with coaxial connection
```

[Image of my_plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs4LQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your image depicts a setup all connected by Ethernet and all on one subnet. It is similar to many and it will work just fine. Make sure the switch is a plain switch (which it likely is).